# Why only the thread that created UI control can access it

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have listened about threading model in .Net that only the thread that have created UI control can access it, not any other thread.

Why is this restriction have been added so far ? May be i am asking some foolish question but i would really like to know what is the logic or limitation behind this model ?

Thanks

Comment: Because the design of the WIndows UI requires it, and .Net is simply a large wrapper around that UI. which was not designed to allow multiple threads to access graphic controls simultaneously. Do some reading here: https://www.google.com/search?q=why+is+Windows+GUI+single+threaded&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: This is hardly exclusive to .NET or Windows. Single-threaded UI is much easier to deal with, just like single-threaded code in general is much easier to deal with, and for exactly the same reasons. When you touch controls accross thread-boundaries, you *must* use synchronization - this just forces you to always handle the synchronization rather than ignoring it.